# How do I pass variable value of one activity to baseactivity in android

Tags: android

I have `BaseActivity` and `LoginActivity` in my application where access token is being fetched from web service. I do not want to save access token in static or shared preference so I want to make it available accessToken to `BaseActivity` from `LoginActivity` so it can be access across the application which extends `BaseActivity` using simple method.

### BaseActivity.java

```
@Override
public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}
```

Any idea how I can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to save access token in static or shared preference so
>   I want to make it available accessToken to BaseActivity from
>   LoginActivity so it can be access across the application which extends
>   BaseActivity using simple method.

if the field is not static each class extending `BaseActivity` will have its own instance of `accessToken`, meaning that this field has to be filled every time. If you want to fetch/fill it only once you could use the `Singleton` pattern. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

E.g. You could use enum to create a thread safe singleton

```
public enum AccessToken {
    INSTANCE("myaccesstoken");

    AccessToken (String accessToken) {
        mAccessToken = accessToken; 
    }

    String mAccessToken;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return mAccessToken;
    }
}
```

and then   `AccessToken.INSTANCE.getAccessToken();`

Comment: can you help me a snippet code for how I can make `Singleton` ?

Comment: What is the lifetime of implementing `Singleton` using `enum`

Comment: Application's one

Comment: what is the meaning of this `INSTANCE("myaccesstoken");`

Comment: it is a constructor. You might want to read more about enum on java

Answer (score -1):

put bundle in one activity and s and another activity get bundle